# Sinatra not loading layout file when URL has 2 sublevels

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this code:

```
# Users page
get '/admin/users' do
  @title = "Admin - Users"
  erb :admin_users
end
```

When the view is rendered, I get the HTML in the ERB file but the layout file does not render. If I change the route to just '/users' everything renders fine. What gives? I originally put the users ERB page in a subdirectory 'views/admin' after finding sample code on how to do that and hit this issue. I thought that was the reason but rather it seems its the URL causing the problem. Anyone else hit this or know a work around?

All my other views work fine as well. This is the first view I've tried the URL pattern with. I also tried this but it didn't affect anything.

```
# Users page
get '/admin/users' do
  @title = "Admin - Users"
  erb :admin_users, :layout => :layout
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, check paths to yours assets in the layout. You should add `/` before.

`<link href='/stylesheets/application.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a subdirectory for the `admin_users` view, you should really save it as `views/admin/users.erb` and then render it with

get '/admin/users' do
  erb :'admin/users'
end

Maybe this will already address your issue. Let me know, if you need more help.

I guess you can get into trouble when you set the view directory for the admin views different from the location of the `layout.erb` file. Have you tried putting a dummy `layout.erb` in the `views/admin/` folder?

Comment: All of what you describe is what I tried initially. I put the users.erb in an views/admin folder and set the route to render '/admin/users' from erb :'admin/users' and I had the same result. It rendered fine but without the layout page. I then copied the layout.erb into that folder thinking it might be looking in the same folder as the view and it didn't matter. I also changed the name of the copied layout file and did erb :'admin/users', layout => admin_layout and that didn't matter either.

Answer (score 0):

You did not showed the exact error your are getting. I assume it is "No such file or directory" for the template "admin_users.erb".

An option is missing on your "erb" call and you should tell Sinatra where to find the template. This has just worked for me:

```
# Users page
get '/admin/users' do
  @title = "Admin - Users"
  erb :'admin/admin_users', :layout_options => { :views => 'views/admin' }
end
```

It renders the template on `views/admin/admin_users.erb` using the layout from `views/admin/layout.erb`